# Shell-less UI in Prism

Tags: c#, prism, prism-4, prism-2

Is is possible to launch a Prism v4 application, skip the Shell initialization/creation/display, and display a specific module's view instead?

For example, suppose I have a Prism app called app.exe. It has a Window class (Shell) that contains the regions for the "full view" of my application.

I want to launch app.exe with a parameter, like this: app.exe /view:MyView

When app.exe launches, I don't want to see the "full view" of my app with MyView displayed within a region of the Shell. I want to go Shell-less! I only want to see MyView displayed in its own window (like a popup) without the Shell being visible.

If I can skip creating the Shell altogether, even better.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

- Not sure about WPF but in Silverlight the RootVisual must be set and it must be at least visual control type.
- How you want to display ChildWindow of 'MyView' ? Something should call it. Are you using InteractionRequest ? You doing it from code-behind ? There's must be some 'base' class who will initialize ChildWindow. If a ChildWindow it's a first window - then it not a ChildWindow it's a Shell.

  My guess - may be you should review your application logic. Don't stick to the names globally. Call it Shell, ChildWindow or PopupWindow it doesn't matter - just build clear picture of application architecture - who goes first ? Does you need a base (Manager) class (as in your example of look-less Shell), event driven ? data driven app ?

Comment: Let me try to clarify: I have a Prism app with 3 modules. I want to launch my app and make only 1 module load and display it's primary view in a window. I only want to see this view in the window, no other Shell UI and no other modules. We're trying to implement a "lite UI" and "full UI" pattern where, based on how the app is launched, either the Shell loads and shows all available UI and modules (full mode), or somehow a specific view in a specific module loads and is displayed in a "bare bones" Shell (no ribbon, no status bar, no tabs etc.) Maybe a PopUp region? Maybe multiple Bootloaders?